# O que é BLOB no javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quando você tenta acessar o link que fica dentro do `src` da tag `vídeo` do youtube, o que acontece é que você simplesmente não consegue acessar, ou o acesso é dificultado, e eu gostaria de saber como fazer esse processo e principalmente saber como ele funciona.

Answer (score 6):

Blob é a definição para *Binary Large Object*, o youtube realiza streams de dados binários em tempo real, de forma que não existe um arquivo físico que é servido no vídeo.

Com uma stream de dados o vídeo é processado e enviado ao mesmo tempo e o browser interpreta e exibe na tela a informação que ele está recebendo em tempo real, isto é o que possibilita a transmissão ao vivo e muitas outras coisas que o Youtube faz. Inclusive não poder baixar o vídeo, porque ele não existe como um arquivo.

Você pode sim fazer o download de uma stream de vídeo com a ferramentas certas que capturam os dados à medida que os mesmos chegam no browser e compõem um novo arquivo.

Comment: A informação sobre baixar está incorreta, mesmo transmissões podem ser baixadas

Comment: Vou escrever melhor, elas podem ser capturadas